# iOS – Check if MFMessageComposeViewController is currently visible

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I need to check if `MFMessageComposeViewController` is currently visible. How can I do that?

What I'm doing right now is:

```
//Get the current visible view controller
ViewController *visible = ...

if([visible isKindOfClass:[MFMessageComposeViewController class]])
// This doesn't work because the class is actually CKSMSComposeController
```

And I can't check for CKSMSComposeController then Xcode will complain about "Use of undeclared identifier 'CKSMSComposeController'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a boolean after you have presented the modal view controller is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your `visible` controller's `parentViewController` property, it's class should be `MFMessageComposeViewController` class (at least in iOS 7).